# How to concatenate pandas series such way

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need function:
`f(pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], [[1, 2, 3]]), pd.Series(['b', 'c', 'd'], [[1, 2, 3]])) -> pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [[1, 3, 5, 3]]))`

Comment: The input is unclear, do you have a series of dictionaries?

Comment: modified, check again

Comment: So you want to add the indices with mapping in the values? You should define the series the other way around and just add

Answer (score 0):

Use *groupby* method of Series
Example:

```
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
b = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], ['b', 'c', 'd'])
c = pd.concat([a,b])
c.groupby(by=c.index).sum()
```

Result:

```
a    1
b    3
c    5
d    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is not how OP defined the series.

Comment: @mozway yes, but index and values could be quickly swapped

Comment: Then you should probably show that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
y = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], ['b', 'c', 'd'])

indices = set(list(x.index) + list(y.index))
x_re, y_re = x.reindex(indices).fillna(0), y.reindex(indices).fillna(0)
result = x_re + y_re
print(result)
```

```
b    3.0
d    3.0
a    1.0
c    5.0
dtype: float64
```